# var name = $('textarea#myTextBox').val(); does not return a String?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, textarea

I'm trying to get the String value out of a text area using

`var name = $('textarea#myTextBox').val();`

However, this seems to output undefined. I know this because I have a check in my JS after this code that says `name = "5"+name+"4";`

I then send `name` to a C++ file using Awesomium, and the name is processed through the below line:

```
String name = Convert::toString(params[L"name"].toString());
```

When I see what my name is set to, it reads "5undefined4"

**EDIT**: My CSS is simply this:

```
#myTextBox {
   position: absolute;
   top: 78%;
   left: 40%;
}
```

I've had my html set as:

```
<textarea id="myTextBox" rows="1" col="20" maxlength="18"></textarea>
```

Which makes the text area "listen" to the CSS and be placed in the correct position, but I get `null` as my string.

I've also tried:

```
<div class="myTextBox">
    <textarea id="nameBox" rows="1" col="20" maxlength="18"></textarea>
</div>
```

Which then the textarea does not listen to the CSS and it still returns `null`

Comment: What does `alert($('textarea#myTextBox').length);` say?

Comment: did you also try $('#myTextBox').val() ?

Comment: @Briz: Your selector is incorrect then.

Comment: @Alex Could you clarify what my "selector" is?

Comment: @Briz: The string you are passing to the jQuery object.

Comment: Inspect your textarea and make sure it's ID really is set to "myTextBox". It sounds like your selector isn't finding anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does `alert($('textarea#myTextBox').length);` say? – alex

> @alex It says 0 – Briz

Your selector is incorrect.

For that selector to work, your HTML should look like...

```
<textarea id="myTextBox" rows="1" cols="1" name="something"></textarea>
```

The `id` attribute is the important one.

Comment: Yes.... the `id` is important....hence why you shouldn't put spelling errors in it ;)

Comment: @alex: Yes. You wrote `myTextBix`. I fixed it for you ;)

Comment: @alex: I edited my question to include the CSS and html. From my first html example, it seems it should be working. Can you take a look?

Comment: Ahh! Got it finally working. I had been combining the wrong things, but with the help of your answer and comments, I was able to sort it all out and now it works. Thank you!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The way I would use jquery with id is to use $('#controlId')

did you try $('#myTextBox').val() ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried all combinations of that sort of thing I could think of. In that case it still outputs undefined

Comment: @Briz you mean you are able to find the element. What is the output of $('#myTextBox').html() ?

Comment: @Briz: Selector is definitely wrong. Show us your HTML and we'll tell you where you messed up :)

Comment: @Mark: I've edited the question to show my CSS and html. Thanks!